# How do I use execute, rather than execute script in SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

In the following code, scheduling.sql is executing properly, while dummy.sql is not. I'm not getting an error message. It just doesn't appear to be doing anything. For dummy.sql, I prefer to use execute, rather than executescript, so I can pass it some parameters. What am I doing wrong here?

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = db.cursor()

with open('scheduling.sql', 'r') as sql_file:
    sql_script = sql_file.read()
cursor.executescript(sql_script)

with open('dummy.sql', 'r') as sql_file:
    sql_script = sql_file.read()
fetch=cursor.fetchone()
while fetch:
    cursor.execute(fetch)
    fetch=cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

It never executes `dummy.sql`. What is `fetch` after `fetch=cursor.fetchone()`  executes ? Guess is something falsey. `fetch...` comes after `execute....`.